# How to force apiserver proxy to use HTTPS in connection to container

Tags: ssl, proxy, kubernetes

I'm trying to connect to `skydns` `etcd` server through `apiserver proxy`, using this doc http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls with command

> curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/certs/ca.crt --header "Authorization:
>   Bearer J9bAdaBGyQUEESCz7k412afmpskoHig7" -sS --cert
>   /etc/pki/etcd/etcd-dns.crt --key /etc/pki/etcd/etcd-dns.key
>   https://95.164.68.160:6443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/2701e09a-b9f7-4b77-b4ad-8438a974ddfe/services/service-f1g5a:2379/v2/keys

but have the error

> Error: 'dial tcp 10.254.63.2:2379: i/o timeout'
>
> Trying to reach: 'http://10.254.63.2:2379/v2/keys'

it looks like it tries to connect to `http` instead of `https`

doc says, that

> proxy to target may use HTTP or HTTPS as chosen by proxy using
>   available information

what information does it use? how to force using of `https`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prefix the service name with "https:"
The following formats are recognized:

```
# Proxies to the first port in the service, using http
https://<master>/api/v1/namespaces/myns/services/myservice/proxy/...

# Proxies to the specified port in the service, using http
https://<master>/api/v1/namespaces/myns/services/myservice:myport/proxy/...

# Proxies to the specified port, using https
https://<master>/api/v1/namespaces/myns/services/https:myservice:myport/proxy/...
```

Comment: Is this in the documentation? I wasn't able to find it.